Using C# and OpenXml how do I delete a cell that has a shared formula?
My excel file is getting corrupted when I delete a cell. The repair error is "Removed Records: Shared formula from /xl/worksheets/sheet1.xml part". I think when I delete a cell with a shared formula I need to remove it from a shared formula table somehow.
To reproduce the error create a new excel file and in cell A1 add the simple formula "=B1". Copy this formula in A1 down to about cell A10. Then run this code. When you open the excel file it will be corrupted.
using DocumentFormat.OpenXml.Packaging;
using DocumentFormat.OpenXml.Spreadsheet;
using System.Linq;

class Program
{
    static void Main()
    {
        string filePath = "c:\\test\\test.xlsx";
        string worksheetName = "Sheet1";

        //get second row
        SpreadsheetDocument spreadsheetdocument = SpreadsheetDocument.Open(filePath, true);
        WorkbookPart workbookpart = spreadsheetdocument.WorkbookPart;
        Sheet sheet = workbookpart.Workbook.Descendants<Sheet>().FirstOrDefault(s => s.Name == worksheetName);
        WorksheetPart worksheetpart = (WorksheetPart)workbookpart.GetPartById(sheet.Id);
        SheetData sheetdata = worksheetpart.Worksheet.Elements<SheetData>().FirstOrDefault();
        Row row = sheetdata.Elements<Row>().FirstOrDefault(r => r.RowIndex == 2);

        //get first cell
        Cell cell = row.Elements<Cell>().FirstOrDefault();

        //delete cell 
        cell.Remove();

        //remove calculation cell from calculation chain
        spreadsheetdocument.WorkbookPart.CalculationChainPart.CalculationChain.Elements<CalculationCell>()
            .FirstOrDefault(cc => cc.CellReference == cell.CellReference)?.Remove();

        //delete calculation chain part if no cells left
        if (spreadsheetdocument.WorkbookPart.CalculationChainPart.CalculationChain.Elements<CalculationCell>().Count() == 0)
        {
            workbookpart.DeletePart(spreadsheetdocument.WorkbookPart.CalculationChainPart);
        }

        //save
        worksheetpart.Worksheet.Save();

        //dispose
        spreadsheetdocument.Dispose();

    }

}


xlsx extension is not OpenXML.  It is a proprietary Microsoft Excel Format.
